# Modify a static Python dictionary through SSH

Tags: python, dictionary, ssh

So I have a python file, lets call it foo.py, located on a remote server. This file essentially houses a static dictionary, which is then used by other processes on this server. I want to be able to SSH into this remote server and modify some of the fields in this static dictionary. I have been using pattern matching and sed to do this up until now, but this is a fairly "dirty" way to do it (not to mention somewhat complex at times). I was wondering if there was a cleaner, easier way to accomplish this?

Some rules: I do not want to copy the file locally, modify it, and send it back. Also, I do not want to copy a script over to the server which does the modifications.

Comment: Time to move up to a database.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not by my hand that this situation exists :(

Comment: You *MAY* use sshfs to access the file. It allows you to mount the remote file system through ssh.

Comment: The code for reading, modifying, and rewriting has to either run on the server or the client. So you have to copy the code to the server or the data to the client and back. You ruled out both. No way to solve this then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a python dictionary for storage and then running the python script to parse it, you might consider using a file type specifically designed for storage. JSON is very similar to python dictionaries, and the [built-in json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) makes importing and exporting very simple. This even works for storing custom python class objects, as long as they can be serialized.

In order to edit it from an ssh session, you can just start up a python interactive shell, import json, load in the file, make your edits, then dump the result back to the file. Here's some example usage:

```
$ ssh user@host
user@host$ python
>>> import json
>>> store = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, name='Jim')
>>> with open('store.json', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(store, f)
... 
>>> with open('store.json', 'r') as f:
...     store2 = json.load(f)
... 
>>> print store2
{u'a': 1, u'c': 3, u'b': 2, u'name': u'Jim'}
>>> store2['a'] = 4
>>> print store2
{u'a': 4, u'c': 3, u'b': 2, u'name': u'Jim'}
>>> with open('store.json', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(store, f)
```

Comment: I am aware of using a JSON, however this is not an option. I have a .py file with a statically defined dictionary inside of it, and I want to modify a couple fields in the static dictionary itself.

Comment: Hmm, okay. But if you have access to the python script, why can't you modify it to load the dictionary from a JSON file?

Comment: Because the python script is what is housing the dictionary itself. Calling it a script is somewhat misleading because literally all that is in this python file is this statically defined dictionary.

Comment: Is the .py file being run by a python interpreter in order to load the dictionary? If so, you could change it to load from JSON. That is, unless the calling code limits availability to the json library, which is possible. In this case, my approach would require access to the calling code.

Comment: If you're doing the edits somewhat manually, there's always vi/vim.